# python subprocess input commands

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to open ConEmu and input my commands there from a python code.

```
cmd= "sample commands"
subprocess.call(['C:\Users\MSI\Downloads\ConEmuPack.151101\ConEmu.exe'])
```

ConEmu is opened, but how do I input commands in the subprocess automatically after conemu is opened?

Comment: Do you want [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)?

Comment: you probably want `proc = subprocess.Popen(...)` to open the command and then from there you  can `proc.stdin.write(...)` the commands.

Comment: Sounds like a use case of https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect